Cookies are not transmitted to the server
I made sure that I have cookies saved on the client, and the authorization itself works. I can get a token through the frontend, but when I try to check for the token on the server, the server just gets nothing, what should I do? :(
Client:
      const checkToken = async () => {
        const token = Cookies.get("authToken");
        console.log("The token is on the client:", token);
      
        if (!token) {
          console.log("There is no token");
          return;
        }
      
        try {
          const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/check", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            credentials: "include", 
          });
      
          console.log("Server responce:", await response.text());
          if (response.status === 200) {
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log("done:", data);
            setUser(data.user); 
          } else {
            console.log("Auth error:", await response.json());
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error checking the token:", error);
        }
      };
      

Server:
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://59e5-185-9-186-241.ngrok-free.app",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
    credentials: true, 
  })
);

app.post("/api/auth/telegram", (req, res) => {
  const userData = req.body;


  if (!validateTelegramAuth(userData)) {
    console.log("Неверная подпись Telegram");
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Incorrect Telegram signature" });
  }


  const token = generateAuthToken(userData);


  res.cookie("authToken", token, {
    httpOnly: true, 
    signed: true, 
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    sameSite: "None", 
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  });

  console.log("The token has been generated and sent:", token);
  return res.json({ token });
});


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Request received: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  console.log("Cookies on the server:", req.cookies);
  next();
});

I turned to chatGPT, searched for solutions on the Internet, disabled http only, signed, secure, samesite, received a token through the client and output it (and it was output)

"disabled http only, signed, secure, samesite" - you need SameSite=None, otherwise the cookie will not be send across different origins. But SameSite=None also requires that you use Secure; and that in turn means you can't make non-HTTPS requests, and still expect the cookie to be send.
